# Sendto folder within a folder destination

Tags: windows

I need to copy a file to another destination folder but would like to be able to select a folder within the selected destination.

I have a large selection of tv 'series name' folders each containing folders called 'season 01', 'season 02' etc.

```
ie d:\TV Series\Vera\season 01
   d:\TV Series\Vera\season 02
   d:\TV Series\Vera\season 02
```

I can set the path to the main folder with all the 'series name' folders and can select any 'series name' folder. This works fine but I would like to be able to select one of the season folders within a 'series name' folder. Sendto does not allow the selection of the contents of a folder and to explore it's content.
Is there any way of doing this?

---

Thanks for your time guys...
At the moment the workable solution I use is to have 45 'series name' folders in the sendto folder. I can right click a file I want to save and select the 'series name' root folder. I then have to go to the folder itself and move the file into it's permanent season folder. I can live with this as it is but would have liked to add the further folder depth selection.
I didn't realise my request for a suggested solution was not allowed. I'll edit the request now.
Thanks.

Comment: What about setting up two File Explorer windows side by side and drag-and-dropping or copy-pasting between them? This seems to me the simplest way to handle a handful of file move tasks. Please note, requests to recommend software are off-topic here on SuperUser.  You may wish to EDIT your question to remove that part of the last couple sentences of your question.

Comment: The windows explorer simply does not facilitate this.  Back in the windows XP days.. you *might have* been able to pull this off but the explorer had been neutered since then. A custom shell extension is probably about as close as you are going to get.  I myself would follow @music2myear advice

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is the best solution I've found which is very simple yet elegant.

It's a small reg file that adds copy to as an option to the right click menu:

```
==== Copy to ===================================================================
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; created by Brady Gavin
; for How-To Geek
; article: https://www.howtogeek.com/509071/how-to-add-move-tocopy-to-into-windows-10s-context-menu/

;Adds the "Copy To Folder" functionality from Windows 7, when you right click files or folders, for easier file management.
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Copy To]
@="{C2FBB630-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}"
================================================================================
```

This works well and opens a folder dialog to select the destination folder.

There is also a Move to option which works in the same way:

```
==== Move to ===================================================================
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; created by Brady Gavin
; for How-To Geek
; article: https://www.howtogeek.com/509071/how-to-add-move-tocopy-to-into-windows-10s-context-menu/

;Adds the "Move To Folder" functionality from Windows 7, when you right click files or folders, for easier file management.
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Move To]
@="{C2FBB631-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}"
================================================================================
```

I hope this may be of interest to others.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing).